# podman cannot run rootless with users from remote auth system as they are not in /etc/shadow

Tags: docker, containers, podman

I'm trying to run podman rootless on a server where users are authenticated via a remote system. Problem is, in this setup, this means `/etc/shadow` does not track the users (normal).

Result is that running `podman run alpine` results in the following:

```
Resolved "alpine" as an alias (/etc/containers/registries.conf.d/000-shortnames.conf)
Trying to pull docker.io/library/alpine:latest...
Getting image source signatures
Copying blob 7264a8db6415 done
Error: copying system image from manifest list: writing blob: adding layer with blob "sha256:7264a8db6415046d36d16ba98b79778e18accee6ffa71850405994cffa9be7de": processing tar file(potentially insufficient UIDs or GIDs available in user namespace (requested 0:42 for /etc/shadow): Check /etc/subuid and /etc/subgid if configured locally and run podman-system-migrate: lchown /etc/shadow: invalid argument): exit status 1
```

By way of testing, I *have* tried just adding the users with appropriate values in `/etc/subuid` and `/etc/subgid`, it results in the above error.

I know I can get the *resolved* shadow entries by running `getent /etc/shadow`

Is it possible to get podman to lift the required information from there?

We don't want to create alt user accounts on the server; getting podman to read config for remote-authenticated users is our primary goal.

---

It seems to be a common issue both on the podman and docker sides:

I have seen [a handful](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/6216591) [of posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69241539/run-docker-commands-without-sudo-without-adding-user-in-group) [about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68670513/rootless-docker-with-windows-ad-auth), but they remain unanswered.

I have checked the requirements for [rootless deployment](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/) of containers in general, and managing [subuid/subgid](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/), but integration with remote-auth users is not covered

I've seen it acknowledged that [LDAP integration is ~difficult](https://rootlesscontaine.rs/caveats/) and a [`subuidless` solution](https://github.com/rootless-containers/subuidless) is in the works but incomplete.

So unless I am missing something, I don't get the impression that this is a use case that is supported in the current state of play?